# Get the metabase path for an IIS entry (Installation stopped because the specified path is not a valid web application)

Tags: asp.net, iis, metabase, aspnet-regiis.exe

I'm by no means a sysadmin so please correct me if I'm wrong.

I want to run aspnet_regiis.exe -s.
This requires the metabase path of my website.

How do I find this metabase path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run aspnet_regiis.exe -lk to see a list of the registered applications, their metabase paths and the version of the .NET framework installed for this application.

Also, here are a couple of links that you can use to find the metabase path:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524682.aspx
- http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/2005/10/25/hacking-iis6-with-metabase-explorer.html
- http://www.codersource.net/csharp_iis_metabase.html

HTH,

Don

Comment: Wow, that first link is a waste of time! It took me 10 mins to figure out the code is not complete...
Not to complain about Don, but complaining about MSDN...

Comment: Is this different on new IIS/.NET versions? when I run aspnet_regiis.exe -lk (from the Visual Studio 2010 command prompt) I just get the help for aspnet_regiis, (which actually includes -lk, but it doesn't seem to work)

Comment: Never mind, just read: "Not supported on Windows Vista and higher versions"

Answer (score 1):

For versions of Windows higher than Vista, try [appcmd](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe), with the "list site" commands:

> %WindowsDirectory%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list site

This should give you the site name and id for all the sites on the system.

The metabase path is of the form

> `/W3SVC/<site id>/Root`

plus the site id.